# can you have multiple "SQL Editor" tabs in SQL-Front mySQL gui

Tags: mysql

i am used to SQL Server and SQL enterprise studio when using databases in my solutions.  I have to use mySQL so i have tried out [SQL-Front gui](http://www.downloadplex.com/Windows/Development/Other/sql-front_71913.html) which seems pretty good.

The one missing thing that is a pain point is that i can't figure how to have multiple queries around at once.  in SQL Server Enterprise manager, it would create a new tab for each new queries so i can i have a number of queries laying around.

In SQL-Front it seems like i can only have a single SQL Editor up at once so i wind up storing SQL queries in notepad locally.

Is there anyway for SQL-Front to have similar behavior to have multiple queries lying around.  I tried leaving multiple queries in the single window and highlighting the query i wanted to run but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [**TOAD for MySql**](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) - does everything you would expect and it's free!  Oh yea and it works just like the sql server management studio you're already used to with multiple tabs for multiple queries.

Enjoy!